# downloading files using UI web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Is it possible to download files implementing UI web iphone in my app? If so where would the files be stored and how can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really download files simply by browsing to them but what you could do is use

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

to analyze the link for a file (say by looking at the extension of last path component) and if you want this kind of file to be downloaded than you could use [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myURLRequest delegate:self]; and all its associated delegate methods to download and store the file in the documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to visualize some known for webview file, it will show you automatically...but if page give back an unknown for webview file (This happened to me with Citrix ica file) webview will give you an error....to solve this problem i used this code (note that here i will allow to download only ica file, but you can change this condition):

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

if([error code]!=102)
{       [self.lblError setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]];
        return;
    }

NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSString * url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"NSErrorFailingURLKey"] ];


NSString *search = @"?";
NSRange result = [url rangeOfString:search];
NSInteger startingPosition;
NSString *fileName,*fileExtention,*fileLocation;
if (result.location != NSNotFound) {
    startingPosition = result.location + result.length;
    fileLocation = [url substringToIndex:result.location];
    fileExtention=[fileLocation pathExtension];
}
else
{
    fileLocation=url;
}

fileName = [fileLocation lastPathComponent];
fileExtention=[fileLocation pathExtension];

//check if file to download if ica file
if(![fileExtention isEqualToString:@"ica"])
    return;

self.lblError.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.lblError.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"downloading %@...",fileName];

NSURL * _url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];


// Get file online
NSData *fileOnline = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_url];

// Write file to the Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
if (!documentsDirectory) {
   // NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
    return;
}
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

//NSLog(@"appFile path: %@",appFile);
[fileOnline writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];

NSURL* aUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];

self.interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: aUrl];
self.interactionController.delegate = self;
self.lblError.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ downloaded",fileName];
[self.interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.lblError.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

}